# Lost name of multi book series about a girl knight and a bipolar guy

Tags: aqua-knight

I'm trying to remember the name of a multi-volume story. Each volume was perhaps 20-25cm x 10cm x 3cm thick, perhaps 120 pages?

- Not in colour - black/white line drawing with some cross hatch shading (not grey scale shading in the rubbed style).
- Story has a girl in a large waterproof underwater + warrior suit, like a knight but bulbous and big.
- She has some sort of "magical" abilities, I think. Not all that sure about this bit.
- She visits castles and keeps, helps people with problems, quests, etc.
- Story has a flying ship thing run by a manic-depressive (bipolar) guy who dresses like a dandy.
- This guy also has a maid/cook girl with an odd disease - she has holes and missing limbs, I think it's called "Null disease". Other people across the lands have it as well.
- Knight girl meets up with flying ship guy.

I remember the books from about 12 years ago, maybe? Not sure when they were written. I also remember them being in English AND left-top-right reading, not right-to-left style.

Answer (score 3):

found it!

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Aqua-Knight-v-Yukito-Kishiro/dp/1569316341/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1398461089&sr=8-1&keywords=aqua+knight

Aqua Knight - Yukito Kishiro

Comment: If you login to the account you used to ask this question, you can mark this answer as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark you'll see to the left of this answer.